# Alphabetize Bitmap Array from Resource C#

Tags: c#, resx

I've been trying to alphabetize this Bitmap Array in C# as the resources aren't alphabetized in the resx file.

I've gotten the resource to an array with this code

```
var resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
System.Drawing.Bitmap[] imageArray = resourceSet.OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
    .Select(i => (System.Drawing.Bitmap)i.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: How do you want to alphabetize a Bitmap array?  What property are you hoping to sort on?

Comment: I'm assigning each image to a picture box with a combo box, and I'd like to be able add images to the resx file, and only have to update the combo box. With this, I'm able to load the images, but they're not in alphabetic order. (I'm not sure if this is the answer you were looking for, I'm sorry if it's not).

Comment: One thing I have tried to no avail was using OfType<DictionaryEntry>().OrderBy(i => i.Value). I was unable to use this, though I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that in your `Select`, you lose the `Key` that you want to sort on.  Use an anonymous type or a new class to keep the name and image:

```
var imageArray = resourceSet
                     .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                     .Select(d => 
                         new
                         {
                            Name = d.Key.ToString(), 
                            Image = (Bitmap)d.Value
                         })
                      .OrderBy(d => d.Name);
                      .ToArray();
```

Comment: How do I call this for the picture box image? this.cardImage.Image = imageArray[comboBox.SelectedIndex]; is no longer working.

Comment: `imageArray[comboBox.SelectedIndex].Image`